# Change the filename before downloading from s3 using filepicker

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3

I am using filepicker v2 for uploading resumes to a s3 bucket. Filepicker adds a hash(i think) before saving them to s3. The download button is a link with the s3.amazon path to that file. Is there any method to change the name before downloading the file. Currently they get a randow charachters then the name of the file uploaded.
With the v3 i can remove the hash with disableStorageKey: true, but i want to do this on download.
Is there a way?
Whith the download attribute i get a forbidden